# Is it possible to receive questions as tweets?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just wanted to know if there is a way to receive my tagged questions as tweets when somebody post a question or I do I have to rely on RSS feeds only? I don't like RSS feeds as I need to configure them on browsers, whereas if i can receive questions as tweets then I can see them on only installed client.

Comment: Where there is a will there is a way...Or do you mean an existing way to accomplish this? Surely you could set up a program to watch the feed and tweet each new post that has desired tags.

Comment: good one :-) but I'm looking for an existing one if already exists. :-P

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it directly, but you could always try something like ifttt.com and configure it to tweet off of your RSS feed.  I have never tried this combination with their service, though.